# If an active directory is given a mail box?

Tags: c#, active-directory

Updating a C# application and I need to test if the current AD user has been assigned a mail box or not....

Can anyone please tell me what attribute will be populated for an active directory user if they are assigned to a mail box.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If an AD user is assigned a mailbox, then attribute `homeMDB` will be populated.

See the snapshot-

[image: Image showing homeMDB attribute for AD user]

You can also read article sharing the same point at [Check if a user has an Exchange mailbox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5053/Check-if-a-user-has-an-Exchange-mailbox)

### Update

Based on my [research and found](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123558(v=exchg.65).aspx), I have discovered that following are the attributes that let you know if a user has been assigned a mailbox or not.

- homeMDB
- homeMTA
- legacyExchangeDN
- mail
- mailNickname
- msExchHomeServerName
- msExchMailboxGuid
- msExchMailboxSecurityDescriptor
- proxyAddresses

Comment: thanks for the reply but homeMDB are not available on my list?

Comment: I have homeDirectory, homeDrive and then initals